# NUnit v3 unit tests not being discovered - "Discover test finished: 0 found"

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit-3.0

**Test class**

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void testtesttest()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

[image]

I followed instructions from [here](http://www.alteridem.net/2017/05/04/test-net-core-nunit-vs2017/).

Why can't I discover my unit tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**.NET Core Solution**

It turns out I had to have a unit test project instead of a class library:

[image: Unit Test project]

I also followed instructions from the MSDN website [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit).

I was running the following in a command prompt to make sure I had the unit test template:

```
dotnet new -i NUnit3.DotNetNew.Template
```

**My NuGet Packages Dependencies**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Update**

As @Lexli pointed out, you don't need the MSTest packages if you are only going to use NUnit tests.

However, make sure you use **.NET Core** and not **.Netcore Standard.** The .NET Core comes with the Microsoft.netCore.App SDK which is needed for running unit tests. Unit tests can't be run with .NET standard class libraries.

### **Projects Referencing .NET Framework 4.0**

In projects where the .NET framework was v4.0 I had to use NUnit version 3.0 - anything higher and the project wasn't discovered.

### **Still not working?**

Try clearing temporary files located in the %TEMP% directory.

Note: This path is generally at `C:\Users\(yourusername)\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: The MSTest related lines can be removed if you only have NUnit needs. Make sure you update `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` to latest (your old project did not), and then most issues would go away.